# how to separate weekday/weekend calculation in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

i know someone has probably asked this but i can't seem to find an answer that works for me.

i have an excel sheet that contains the sales and dates of a company.

i want to calculate the average of the sales made during weekday/weekend receptively, and use that average to calculate any outliers such as a sudden drop increase/decrease in sales.

i have created a calculation to identify between weekday/weekend

```
IF

    DATENAME('weekday', [Date]) = "Saturday"

OR DATENAME('weekday', [Date]) = "Sunday"

  THEN "Weekend"
```

[Day Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m652u.png)

i have also created a calculation that calculates the average

```
INT(SUM(
IF [Day] = 'Weekday'
THEN [Number of Records]/22

ELSE
[Number of Records]/8
END ))
```

[Average Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvvAy.png)

this is my calculation to calculate outliers 20% higher/below the average

```
[Number of Records] * 1.2 > [Average]

OR 

[Number of Records] * 0.8 < [Average]
```

[Outlier Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRaa4.png)

but it doesn't seem to be working when i put the outlier calculation into "color". the bar chart remains the same

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dELjz.png)

how do i go about resolving this? is my calculations wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your graph, the average is calculated at the level of date, for that reason is not working (is always true). To fix this, you have to use [Level of Details](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm) expressions.

Also, considering you want to calculate the average of the sales made during weekday/weekend, your calculations should use the measure *Sales* instead *Number of Records*.

The average calculation would look like this:
`{FIXED [Day]: AVG([Sales])}`

And the outlier calculation: 
`[Sales] > 1.2 * [Average] OR [Sales] < 0.8 * [Average]`